# How do I get XTNDConnect PC working again?

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall, licensing

On Windows (XPSP3), I need to use a dead-ware application past its 30-day trial period. The editor has gone bankrupt a long time ago, so there's just no way to buy a license.

So I need to completely wipe out the trial version every month, and start from a clean base.

I tried [Cleanse Uninstaller Pro](http://www.zardssoftware.com/), but it leaves stuff behind, so the trial version detects that it's past the time limit and refuses to proceed.

Does someone know of a really good uninstaller for Windows that I could try?

---

Edit: Thanks for the links, but even Revo Uninstaller and Total Uninstaller fail removing all traces of [the program](http://www.softlow.com/pocket-pc/communications/synchronization/commercial/xtndconnect-pc-esi-9100c-elc.html) now that (after I made a mistake) it found out that the trial period is over. It looks like the protection provided by Vbox is pretty strong :-/

Answer (score 5):

You can buy XTNDConnect PC [on the Sybase website](http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/xtndconnectpc).

Comment: Yeah this blew my mind, I typed `XTNDConnect` into Google and this was the first thing I got. "so there's just no way to buy a license"

Comment: @todda.speot.is: I'm confused over your comment, my link clearly allows you to buy it...

Comment: @todda.speot.is: And I am quoting reality...

Comment: I'm being sarcastic...

Comment: +2 @todda.speot.is: And I'm not, I'm being confuzzled... :)

Comment: I didn't mention that I need a much older version, which is no longer for sale.

Comment: @OverTheRainbow: Please update your question to include why you need the much older version, however the company does still exist so what you ask is rather illegal...

Answer (score 0):

Revo is my choice.

You can easily download and install it from: ninite.com

Its advanced mode really destroys anything :)

It really depends on how your application saves its trial period information but you could give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

SVS is probably the best solution for this, despite, kind of being shoved into a filing cabinet at the bottom of a cabinet, in a bathroom with a sign saying, warning! BEWARE OF LEOPARD

you can apparently still get a copy of SVS [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-get-svs-download-svs-21) - i use svs 2.1, and use the key you can get from the url for the home version . Just install the software into a new layer, use, and after 30 days, you can discard the whole installation or deactivate it

Its dead simple once you get the hang of it, and it will ensure you throw out everything the installer did.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [MSIZAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the past and had some success with it, it might rely on you knowing the product code or having an MSI file from which the software was installed from.