# Application to take snapshot of files/registry?

Tags: windows, monitoring

To investigate how a Windows application works, I need a software that will take a snapshot of the whole disk, including the registry and hidden/protected files, take a second snapshot after running the application, and show what changes were made.

I tried the free [WhatChanged](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php#tools), but it takes a very long time to compute the changes.

Does someone know of a good application, either open-source or commercial?

---

Edit: I also tried InCtrl5, but it seems to miss some files.

---

Edit: For those looking for the same kind of application, [RegShot](http://regshot.sourceforge.net/) can take snapshots of the Registry and the file system.

Comment: Is this continuing in your quest to circumvent the protection on the software on your [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/296380/how-do-i-get-xtndconnect-pc-working-again) for which a paid version has been suggested?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that I need a much older version, which is no longer for sale, hence the need to keep running the time-limited trial. I did offer to buy a license, but got no reply.

Comment: Many installer apps can detect all these changes.  I know Wyse Installer used to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check DiskPulse: http://www.diskpulse.com

It will show you all file system changes in real-time.